# Polynomial expansion of operator

Tags: functions, function-construction, symbolic, polynomials, operators

I am new to Mathematica, I am trying to generate the polynomial function of a operator. So for example, the operator $L $ is $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} $, and I want to generate the polynomial $ \sum_{n=0}^{n=k} (L/2)^n$ and apply that polynomial operator to a function. I was trying to use Nest, any help??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Define

```
L = (1/2) (D[#, x] + D[#, y]) &
```

We see that `L` works as desired.  For instance:

```
Simplify[Nest[L, f[x, y], 3]]
(* (Derivative[0, 3][f][x, y] + 3*Derivative[1, 2][f][x, y] + 3*Derivative[2, 1][f][x, y] +
   Derivative[3, 0][f][x, y])/8 *)
```

And the `Sum` can be constructed in a similar manner.  For instance:

```
Simplify[Sum[Nest[L, f[x, y], n], {n, 0, 3}]]
(* (8*f[x, y] + 4*Derivative[0, 1][f][x, y] + 2*Derivative[0, 2][f][x, y] +
    Derivative[0, 3][f][x, y] + 4*Derivative[1, 0][f][x, y] + 
    4*Derivative[1, 1][f][x, y] + 3*Derivative[1, 2][f][x, y] + 2*Derivative[2, 0][f][x, y] +
    3*Derivative[2, 1][f][x, y] + Derivative[3, 0][f][x, y])/8 *)
```

**Update**

As kindly pointed out by @b.gates... in the Comment below, computation of the final result can be simplified with `NestList`. (Thanks!)

```
Simplify[Total[NestList[L, f[x, y], 3]]]
```

Comment: You can make it more efficient by using `NestList` as in `Simplify[Total[NestList[L, f[x, y], 3]]]`.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a function `makeOperator` that takes any polynomial together with a replacement rule that maps the desired variable onto the desired operator. It outputs the result as a new operator:

```
Clear[makeOperator]; 
makeOperator[poly_, Rule[x_, op_]] /; PolynomialQ[poly, x] := 
 Module[{f},
  Function[#1, #2] & @@ {f, Expand[poly]} /. 
   Power[x, n_: 1] :> Nest[op, f, n]]
```

I define operators using `Function`. Since that has attribute `HoldAll`, the necessary replacements in the polynomial have to be done outside the `Function` body, and are injected afterwards using `Apply` (`@@`). The pattern `Power[x, n_: 1]` detects powers of the variable (including first powers) and replaces them by `Nest`. `Expand` makes sure that the polynomial is in a canonical form before doing the replacements, in particular it eliminates parentheses like $x(x+c)$.

Here is a test with the operator `L` in the question, and a Hermite polynomial:

```
Clear[x, y];
L = Function[f, D[f, x] + D[f, y]];

hp = HermiteH[5, x]

(* ==> 120 x - 160 x^3 + 32 x^5 *)

hpOp = makeOperator[hp, x -> L];

hpOp[ψ[x, y]]
```

$$120
   \left(\frac{\partial \psi
   }{\partial x}+\frac{\partial
   \psi }{\partial y}\right)\\
-160 \left(3 \frac{\partial ^3\psi
   }{\partial x^2\, \partial y}+3
   \frac{\partial ^3\psi }{\partial
   x\, \partial y^2}+\frac{\partial
   ^3\psi }{\partial
   x^3}+\frac{\partial ^3\psi
   }{\partial y^3}\right)\\+32
   \left(5 \frac{\partial ^5\psi
   }{\partial x^4\, \partial y}+10
   \frac{\partial ^5\psi }{\partial
   x^3\, \partial y^2}+10
   \frac{\partial ^5\psi }{\partial
   x^2\, \partial y^3}+5
   \frac{\partial ^5\psi }{\partial
   x\, \partial y^4}+\frac{\partial
   ^5\psi }{\partial
   x^5}+\frac{\partial ^5\psi
   }{\partial y^5}\right)$$