# A function which maps $(ax + by)(cx + dy) \mapsto (a \partial_x + b \partial_y) (c \partial_x + d \partial_y)$

Tags: functions, function-construction, operators

I am new to Mathematica and, as the title says, looking for a way of mapping (for example) the polynomial $$(ax + by)(cx + dy) \mapsto \left(a \frac{\partial}{\partial x} + b \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right) \left(c \frac{\partial}{\partial x} + d \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right) \\ = ac \frac{\partial^2}{\partial_x^2} + (ac + bd) \frac{\partial}{\partial_x}\frac{\partial}{\partial_y} + bd \frac{\partial^2}{\partial_y^2},$$ where the latter operator operates on some predefined function. The $\{a,b,c,d\}$ are constants.

Of course this is simple to do by hand in the case shown above, but I will need to be doing this for rather large polynomials where the manual way is not possible. A systematic approach of some kind would be appreciated.

Thanks to anyone who can help me.

Comment: Closely related, but just for a single operator: [Polynomial expansion of operator](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/72433/245). You can use `makeOperator` from my answer here, too, because your example doesn't contain any operators that don't commute. If that were the case, one would have to do some additional work.

Comment: The parameters `{a,b,c,d}` are intended as constants (that is, independent of `{x,y}`)?

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe something like the following:

```
L /: L[x___]L[y___] := Sort @ L[x,y]
L /: Power[L[x__], n_Integer?Positive] := L @@ Flatten @ ConstantArray[{x}, n]

toOperator[expr_, var_] := With[
    {op = Collect[expr /. v:var->L[v], _L] /. L[x__] -> Inactive[D][#, x]},
    Activate @ Function @ op
]
```

For the OP example:

```
toOperator[(a x + b y)(c x + d y), x|y] //TeXForm
```

$(a d+b c) \frac{\partial ^2\text{$\#$1}}{\partial x\, \partial y}+a c \frac{\partial ^2\text{$\#$1}}{\partial x\, \partial x}+b d \frac{\partial
   ^2\text{$\#$1}}{\partial y\, \partial y}\&$

Comment: Excellent! I have spent some time trying to understand this solution (I'm a novice wrt Mathematica) and I cannot quite get it. But I am extremely happy that you've found a solution. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3):

I have one solution.

```
ClearAll[PolyMap];
PolyMap[p1_ + p2_, vars_] /; (PolynomialQ[p1, vars] && PolynomialQ[p2, vars]) :=  PolyMap[p1, vars] + PolyMap[p2, vars];
PolyMap[a_, vars_] /; VectorQ[vars, ! MemberQ[a, #, Infinity] &] := a*# &;
PolyMap[a_*x_, vars_] /; (VectorQ[vars, ! MemberQ[a, #, Infinity] &] && MemberQ[vars, x]) := a D[#, x] &;
PolyMap[a_*x_^n_, vars_] /; (IntegerQ@n && n > 0 && MemberQ[vars, x] && VectorQ[vars, ! MemberQ[a, #, Infinity] &]) := a*D[#, {x, n}] &;
PolyMap[a_*x_,vars_] /; (PolynomialQ[a x, vars] && MemberQ[vars, x]) := D[#, x] &@*PolyMap[a, vars];
PolyMap[a_*x_^n_, vars_] /; (PolynomialQ[a x^n, vars] && IntegerQ@n && n > 0&& MemberQ[vars, x]) := D[#, {x, n}] &@*PolyMap[a, vars];
```

Here is an Example:

```
PolyMap[a x^2 + b x y^4 + c + c/d x y, {x, y}]
```

[image]

It looks a little of ugly, but it works:

```
PolyMap[a x^2 + b x y^4 + c + c/d x y, {x, y}][x^3 y^3 z^3] // Through
(*(9 c x^2 y^2 z^3)/d + 6 a x y^3 z^3 + c x^3 y^3 z^3*)
```