# define an operator

Tags: operators

How is it possible to define the operator
$(x+\frac{d}{dx})^n$ as a function of $n$?
I use

```
 op[x_] = (x + D[#, x]) &;
```

with the action on, for example, $\cos(x)$

```
 op[x][Cos[x]]
```

for $n=1$. How is it possible to extend the definition for an arbitrary $n$?

Comment: What is the expected output of your example ?

Comment: I think your initial function should be defined as           op[x_] = (x*# + D[#, x]) &;      This is what you want right?

Comment: @ b.gatessucks,  the desired output is $(x+d/dx)^n f(x)$ for any user-defined function $f(x)$.

Comment: @Buddha u r right

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that you want to apply the following operator $n$ times:

```
 op[x_] = (x*# + D[#, x]) &
```

Otherwise you add the $x$ rather than apply it as an operator.

I do these in a recursive function way:

```
 Clear[op]
 op[x_, n_] := op[x, n] = (x*# + D[#, x]) &[op[x, n - 1]];
 op[x, 0] = Cos[x];
```

Answer (score 4):

Well, apparently using the `Nest` command you can do it even more clearly as I have seen in "[another post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/72433/polynomial-expansion-of-operator)". Here is the more simple way:

```
  op[x_,n_,input_]:=Expand@Nest[(x*# + D[#, x]) &,input,n]
```

I have added the `Expand` to simplify the final expression. You can just replace the `input` with the desired function when calling the function or I believe with your syntax you can use:

```
  op[x,3,#]&[Cos[x]]
```

I have added this because with recursive functions you have to remember to clear the definition.

Answer (score 2):

What about

```
op[f_, i_] := Nest[x # + D[#, x] &, f[x], i]
```

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
op[x_, n_] = (x + D[#, {x, n}]) &;
```

??

For example,

```
op[x, 3][x^3]

(*  6 + x  *)
```

Have fun!

Comment: your suggestion is $x+\frac{d^n}{dx^n}$ which is not the operator needed